# Removing a prefab on click

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

So I have spawned a PauseMenu prefab that is instantiated when players click "p". I want the menu to disappear when the playersrecommence play. However, using Destroy(prefab) merely destroyed the actual prefab from the project as opposed to removing the prefab from the game...

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to make teh pause screen responsive to user input?

Comment: Why not enable/disable the object when key is pressed ?

Answer (score 2):

Do not destroy the UI object as you may need it later in the game.
Just do not show it when you don't have to.

Do like,

```
uiObject.SetActive(false); // to hide it, technically disable it.
uiObject.SetActive(true); // to show the object
```

Comment: A great solution. Simple and easy to hide. Love it

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to use a [`SceneManager`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html) `GameObject`. This is something that will be inside a possible `GameManager` object. These two will be inside your game the entire run. A `SceneManager` would handle things such as: music playing, sound effects, enemy management, and player management. Splitting up functions and handling into multiple files get's semi-confusing, but in the long run when setting up games, plan for a bit of legacy. Great for reusing on projects after the fact. I still go to old games I've made and copy classes and prefabs, and one of the most used is my `SceneManager` and `GameManager` just for simplicity in the long run.